# Problems with mesh sorting for transparent textures (with alpha channel)

Tags: javascript, three.js, glsl, webgl, shader

We are trying to render mesh hairs in three.js.

Common issue with objects sorting is not allowed because of huge number of parts of hair and we turn camera around a head. Objects order is constantly changing.

We have implemented Weighted, Blended Order-Independent Transparency using following depth based weight function as suggested by different papers:

casual-effects.blogspot.in/2014/03/weighted-blended-order-independent.html

Overlapping two transparent planes:
http://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/kashvi/oit_2.html

Depth based weight function:

```
pow( a, 1.0 ) * clamp( 10.0 / ( 1e-5 + pow( abs( z2 ) / 5.0, 1.0 ) + pow( abs( z2 ) / 200.0, 1.0 ) ), 1e-2, 3e3 );
```

Alpha channel :

```
float ai = color.a;
vec3 Ci = color.rgb * ai;
gl_FragColor = vec4( Ci, ai ) * w( ai );
```

[[image: improper overlapping hairs]]

Is it possible for you to guide me to some resources for appropriate weight function which is capable to properly?

Comment: Alternate suggestion: Instead of OIT, consider using alpa test: `if ( textel.a < 0.5 ) discard;`

Comment: We got some problems on the edges http://www.babylonjs.com/CYOS/#GDHOS

Comment: (1) What does that demo have to do with the original question? (2) Try turning off mipmapping of the checkerboard texture.

Comment: Actually we are trying to make volume hair with texture with alpha channel
Just see link in the initial question. Demo implements OIT 
1) 3D opaque surfaces to a primary framebuffer
2) 3D transparency accumulation to an off-screen framebuffer
3) 2D compositing transparency over the primary framebuffer
But we cant coup with overlapping body and hair since no depth information is available.
http://c2n.me/3pyf2Bs